# How to redirect users to another page?

Tags: php

I need to redirect users that visit a certain page without providing specific parameters in a query string. How to redirect users to another page the right way? So that the search engines would not penalize me for it.

Comment: @Col: Looks like Daniel A. Lemming provided a pretty good answer below.

Comment: @Robert Harvey you cannot be sure though

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php
    Header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    Header("Location: http://www.new-url.com");
    exit();
?>
```

The moved permanently is what helps with search engines.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($condition){
 header('Location: http://example.com');
 exit();
}
```

will do it.  Don't forget the `exit()`!

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli.  Point taken. And as Daniel wrote, a 301 header would do it.  But the user doesn't say why he is forwarding. Perhaps a 300 or a 307 might be more appropriate in his case.

Comment: "300 Multiple Choices"? Surely not. Did you mean "303 Sea Otter"?

Comment: @Piskvor: Multiple choices can be used if you have different subdomains for different devices.  Though, if I had a Sea Otter...

Comment: Well, it's "See Other", actually; but the browsers only care about numerical codes :o) Do current browsers select the most appropriate version automatically when presented with a 300?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
 
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Instead of  http://www.google.com, you can write your own URL where you want to redirect your page.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    Header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
    Header("Location: http://www.new-url.com");
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: An infestation of excess dots, apparently ;) Also, 302 is Found, 307 is Moved Temporarily.