# How can I redirect a php page to another php page?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to redirect users to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864522/how-to-redirect-users-to-another-page)

I'm a beginner in the programming field....I want to redirect a php page to another one..How is it possible in the most easiest way? My concept is just to move,to the home page from the login page after doing the checking of user id and password.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<?php
   header("Location: your url");
   exit;
?>
```

Comment: Note that if you want to link to another website you have to put http:// in front of the www for it to work.

Comment: @RickHoving of course. it is trivial. you should specify protocol so that url is valid.

Answer (score 7):

While all of the other answers work, they all have one big problem: it is up to the browser to decide what to do if they encounter a Location header. Usually browser stop processing the request and redirect to the URI indicated with the Location header. But a malicious user could just ignore the Location header and continue its request. Furthermore there may be other things that cause the php interpreter to continue evaluating the script past the Location header, which is not what you intended.

Image this:

```
<?php
if (!logged_id()) {
    header("Location:login.php");
}

delete_everything();
?>
```

What you want and expected is that not logged in users are redirected to the login page, so that only logged in users can delete_everything. But if the script gets executed past the Location header still everything gets deleted. Thus, it is import to ALWAYS put an **exit** after a Location header, like this:

```
<?php
if (!logged_id()) {
    header("Location:login.php");
    exit; // <- don't forget this!
}

delete_everything();
?>
```

So, to answer your question: to redirect from a php page to another page (not just php, you can redirect to any page this way), use this:

```
<?php 

header("Location:http://www.example.com/some_page.php"); 
exit; // <- don't forget this!

?>
```

Small note: the HTTP standard says that you must provide absolute URLs in the Location header (http://... like in my example above) even if you just want to redirect to another file on the same domain. But in practice relative URLs (Location:some_page.php) work in all browsers, though not being standard compliant.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply....

Comment: The next [HTTP/1.1 revivision ("HTTPbis")](http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/) explicitly allows relative URLs for the Location: header, to ratify the actual current standard practices.

Answer (score 2):

Send a `Location` header to redirect. Keep in mind this only works before any other output is sent.

```
header('Location: index.php'); // redirect to index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php header('Location: /login.php'); ?>
```

The above php script redirects the user to login.php within the same site

Comment: @MrCode chat is finished :) ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
header('Location: http://www.google.com'); //Send browser to http://www.google.com
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

can use this to redirect

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=index.php" />';
```

the content=1 can be change to different value to increase the delay before redirection

Comment: i always use meta tags to redirect.find it easier to manipulate.

Comment: @s3polz:i'm unable to understand with these meta tags... can u briefly explain it...

Comment: this meta tags will redirect to new page.
i use this with my login module, put this code after i finished all login authentication process.
so basically, after a user successfully logged in, they will be redirected to index.php after 1 second delay

Comment: What is wrong with this solution? According to https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-redirect-a-web-page-in-html.html this is "The simplest way to redirect to another URL ". But "Some browsers do not correctly render the <meta> refresh tag, so before the next page loads, the user can see a flash as a page."

Answer (score 0):

simply you can put this and you will be redirected.

```
<?php 

header("Location: your_page_name.php");
```

// your_page_name.php can be any page where you want to redirect

```
?>
```